# How to extract the json data from json array and also fetch the rows having json column value as null

Tags: c#, .net, database, postgresql

Initially, I have 3 rows in table and "TimeCounterTotals" is the json array column in that table. Out of those 3 rows, I have 1 row where "TimeCounterTotals" is null. So, I want to extract json data from the column and I used this query to extract json data from json column. This query is working but the json data is extracted only where "TimeCounterTotals" column is not null and the query returns 6 rows. The row which had "TimeCounterTotals" as null, is not returned and is vanished. Can anyone help me how can I get the 7th row where "TimeCounterTotals" is not null. Please Help.

```
select 
    "TimeCounterTotals",
    "TimeTotal", "TimeCounterId"
from "TimeCalculationAndApprovals",
json_to_recordset(cast("TimeCalculationAndApprovals"."TimeCounterTotals" as json)) 
as x("TimeTotal" decimal, "TimeCounterId" varchar)



and here is "TimeCounterTotals" data stored in single row for reference,

[
    {
        "TimeTotal": 26100,
        "TimeCounterId": "d5920994-3d85-41f1-8801-956139813a84"
    },
    {
        "TimeTotal": 900,
        "TimeCounterId": "fee81656-4386-49f3-b854-0ec10b949283"
    },
    {
        "TimeTotal": 0,
        "TimeCounterId": "cfe80210-42d7-4b9c-83f8-edbee969b961"
    }
]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHphP.png
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to do. Can you post a row/col example of your data?

Comment: I have "TimeCounterTotals" as "json" column in table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this return what you are trying to get?

```
select "TimeCounterTotals",
       "TimeTotal", "TimeCounterId"
  from "TimeCalculationAndApprovals",
  left join lateral (
     select * from json_to_recordset(cast("TimeCalculationAndApprovals"."TimeCounterTotals" as json)) 
as x("TimeTotal" decimal, "TimeCounterId" varchar)) a on true;
```